# Резиновая верстка

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в стилях css сделать как на сайте spaces.ru, в браузере 100% масштаб, а у сайта где-то 140%, как сделать также?

Comment: это всмысле? может там font-size:medium 

Comment: width:100%

Comment: 140% чего? может 146%?

Comment: А нельзя ли просто увеличить размер шрифта, и другие размеры побольше сделать? В чём загвоздка-то?

Answer (score 1):

В пользовательские стили браузера (ну или в каком-то аналогичном расширении) прописать:

```
body {
  zoom: 140%;
}
```

или

```
body {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Поддержка:
[zoom](http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom) - все браузеры кроме FF и классической Оперы,
[transform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) - все современные браузеры (может понадобиться префикс webkit или moz).

Answer (score 0):

*Ахаха,* не знаю зачем вам, но:

```
body {
 width: 140%;   
}
```

Comment: более верный ответ

Answer (score 0):

На spaces.ru стиль кешируется + для каждого устройства разный. 
Попробуй на компе изменить название браузера на Opera Mini.

Comment: и что изменится?

Comment: насчет кешировки возможно Вы правы

Comment: На разных браузерах разные CSS стили

Answer (score 0):

Верстайте в **em**

С уважением, Кэп